# Find the sets $A$ and $B$ such that: $A \cup B = [0,1], m(A)=0,$ and $B$ is a countable union of nowhere dense, closed sets.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have some sort of answer, but I believe it to be incorrect. I would like to hear some thoughts on this question/answer , or if this answer isn't correct if someone could provide a valid one.

$$A=[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q=\{q_1,q_2,...,q_n,..\} \\ \text{ Let's take a small $\varepsilon > 0$ and make the sets }\\  B_i=((q_i-\varepsilon,q_i+ \varepsilon )\cap[0,1])\cap \mathbb I$$ then $$ B_i ^c=((q_i-\varepsilon, q_i + \varepsilon)\cap[0,1])\cap \mathbb Q \cup [0,q_i-\varepsilon]\cup [q_i+ \varepsilon,1]$$

Then it says that $B_i^c$ are everywhere dense on $[0,1]$, $(\alpha,\beta)\in [0,1], $ $$B=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i \\ A = \mathbb Q \cap[0,1] \\ A \cup B =[0,1].$$

I doubt that $B_i$ are nowhere dense. Thoughts?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sets $B_i$ are neither nowhere dense nor closed in $[0,1]$: the closure of $B_i$ is

$$[q_i-\epsilon,q_i+\epsilon]\cap[0,1]\;.$$

HINT: For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $C_n$ be a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) in $[0,1]$ of measure $1-2^{-n}$, and let $B=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}C_n$.

Comment: I would be forever in your debt if you could type that out. :) I have a exam coming up in 2 days